# How to setup a dockerfile that needs to access s3 and will be pushed to ECR running in ECS

Tags: docker, dockerfile, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I'm new to docker and AWS ECR & ECS services

I have a small web scraper image running locally, and I'm now trying to move it to AWS.

The web scraper result will be saved in a.txt which has been moved to s3, so the web scraper app needs to read a.txt in the beginning, modify it and update it at the end. To be more specific:
The below script in dockerfile moves data from s3 into container:

```
from python:3.7-slim
run aws s3 cp s3://bucket_name/path_to_a.txt local_path_to_a.txt
```

And then, app.py will read data and process it. At the end of code, following script will update the a.txt in s3:

```
boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket_name).upload_file(local_path_to_a.txt, s3://bucket_name/path_to_a.txt)
```

This is my current workflow, so in short, the dockerfile will need to copy files from s3 into container, and script app.py will write back.

Now I'm into the problem:
To build the image locally to push into ECR, I need to give the aws access to dockerfile:

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental
run --mount=type=secret,id=aws,target=/root/.aws/credentials \
aws s3 cp s3://bucket_name/path_to_a.txt local_path_to_a.txt
```

Hence, my quesiton is this the correct way to work in ECR + ECS? I understand I may need to give the container access by setting up IAM role, however, I still need to build the image locally without any error, which requires the aws access from local machine.

Comment: Do you really need to copy the file into the image at *build* time? Or is this something that should be happening at *run* time?

Comment: @larsks, A good one, I can adjust to read data during runtime. I want to get answer of this question more to understand if the above process works, and if so how it works. Or, do you suggest the data transformation and interaction should/usually only be done during run time rather than build time?

Comment: It was more a question about the architecture of your project: if the data is relatively static, so you're not constantly building new images just to incorporate changed data, copying the data in at build time may make sense. But if the data is dynamic, it probably makes more sense to delegate the fetch to runtime so that you can continue to use a single image.

Answer (score 2):

A better workflow in my opinion would be to create a container image that only contains a Python application that does the following:

- copy data to the container from S3
- work on data in the container to produce a new data version
- put (new) data from container back to S3

In order to do this you need two macro workflows:

1. one that build the image and push it to ECR. You could do this locally (your laptop needs to have creds to be able to push to ECR) or through a service such as `CodeBuild` (the build project needs to have an IAM role associated to it that can push to ECR).
2. the second workflow would consist in deploying an ECS task that pulls your container image and runs it. The ECS task will need to have an IAM role that would allow it to pull from ECR (in addition to read/put to S3).

Answer (score 0):

For the AWS commands to work you need to setup AWS access key and secret key inside the docker image which can be ingested via env variable. But it is not a recommended best practice.

If your automating the process then you can have a EC2 instance or codebuild with proper IAM roles to download files from S3 before the docker build